# Optimising Image Sizes in App - iPhone

Tags: iphone, optimization, sdk, xcode4, size

I have an iPhone app which contains around 80 PNG format images measuring 300x300 pixels. The app is just under the 10MB threshold.

I'd like to add more images to the app but want to keep it under 10MB. Is there anyway I can make the images smaller or some other way of reducing the bundle size ?

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can handle smaller images, you can decreese the size of the current images like so:

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

I usually put this method in the UIImage+scale.h category.

I am not sure about the optimisation of the png's that would stay in the same size.

Answer (score 0):

You could fallback to jpeg for photos. Jpeg offers a way-better compression. Using utilties like [pngcrush](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pngcrush) and [pngout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNGOUT) should be helpful according to this [article](http://www.myiphoneadventure.com/xcode_with_the_iphone_sdk/squeezing-png-images-for-iphone-development).